# Extract (two) length characters elements in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my for loop. It looks into the list and it prints out the elements that are '2' characters in length.
I'm Trying to see if a function can do this as well:

```
listo = ['esto', 'es', 'un', 'poco', 'dificil', 'y', 'si']

for fun in listo:    
    x = fun.strip()
    if len(x) == 2:
            print (x)  # Yes extra indentation

   output=es
          un
          si
```

Made it into a function:

```
listo = ['esto', 'es', 'un', 'poco', 'dificil', 'y', 'si']

def func():
    a = listo.strip()
    if len(a) <=2:
        print(a)
```

But `strip` doesn't work so I removed it and left it looking for:

```
if len(a) <= 2
```

and now there is no error but it doesn't work as well. What am I missing here, what would be the alternative for `strip` inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `strip()` is taking the place of a very much needed `for` loop.

Instead, replace it with a `for` loop:

```
def func(lst):
    for a in lst:
        if len(a) <=2:
            print(a)
```

Also, your 1<sup>st</sup> example makes no sense. You have a list named `list` (don't do this, it shadows the built-in), and then you loop over `stuff`<sup>?</sup>, and it raises no error? Also, in the 2<sup>nd</sup> example, you have `list.strip()` which would raise an error.

Comment: Yes I thought I said that, the 'strip' creates an error. I'm sorry I tried my best with the English that I know. Wow I dont know why I didnt think about placing the forloop inside a function... Thank you so much.

Comment: Looks like I would still need the 'strip' isndie my function

Comment: yes, but you would call `a = a.strip()` right before the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
listo = ['esto', 'es', 'un', 'poco', 'dificil', 'y', 'si']

def func():
    for line in listo:
        aa = line.strip()
        if len(aa) ==2:
                print(aa)
```

Thanks everyone I dont know why I just didnt palce the for loop inside the function..

Answer (score 0):

```
def strip(n='Hello, world!',x=' '):
  if type(x) == "<class 'str'>":
    x = [x]
  for i in x:
    l = ''
    r = n.split(i) # If not working, use r = series.n.split(i) or r = pd.series.n.split(i), and import pandas as pd.
    for j in r:
      l += j
    n = l
  return n
```

This works like `print(strip('Hello, world!',[',',' ','!']))`. It strips the first argument (Hello, world!) to all the elements in the second argument (A space, a comma, and an exclamation mark), giving us `Helloworld`.

Comment: Note: This includes `split()`, so you may need panda.

Comment: First of all there is no need to comment on your answer, just [edit] it. Second, `split` is a built-in, what does it have to do with panda(s?)?

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Well, sorry for the typo, it's panda*s*. On some compilers, `split`, I don't think is built-in, although that's a little out of the ordinary. Pandas, though, include serie splits. Sometimes we need this in the code if the original is not working.

Comment: I just don't see what pandas have to do here... The op is not using a dataframe and `split` is just a string method